# Intercept back button to Go back to previous page if pressed once and exit if twice

Tags: java, android

I've been working in an android app which contain mainly local html pages with only one Mainactivity. I'm using this code to exit the app which when pressed twice will exit the app. 
For example I have two html files inside assets folder and one page link to other. If I have gone from A to B , then if back button is pressed once..it should redirect me to previous page and if pressed twice will exit the app. For now code I'm using to exit the app if pressed twice is...

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
    super.onBackPressed();
    return;
}

this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce=false;                       
    }
}, 2000);
```

}

I would like to implement method if pressed once will redirect to previous page and if pressed twice will exit the app. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it like this :

```
boolean doubleBackToExitPressed = false;
long lastBackPressTime = 0;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // assuming the gap between two presses is 500ms
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    if (currentTime - lastBackPressTime < 500) {
        doubleBackToExitPressed = true;
        super.onBackPressed();
        return;
    } else {
        lastBackPressTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!doubleBackToExitPressed) {
                 // go to the previous webpage
            } else {
                doubleBackToExitPressed = false;
            }
        }
    }, 510); // trigger this after 510 milli seconds
}
```

In this code, on the first back-press, the current time is saved, and on the second back-press, its compared with lastBackPressTime. If the gap is less than 500 milli seconds, the `super.onBackPressed()` is called.

The code inside the handler triggers after 510 milli seconds, and checks if `doubleBackToExitPressed` is `false`.

Comment: well it works same as I have posted the code. Say I have two local html files and one html files is linked to another, consider A to B and B to A. Now what I want is If I have gone from A to B then, on pressing Back button will redirect to original or previous page i.e A and if pressed twice will exit the app. I hope I have explained well.

Comment: You are using `WebView` to display the pages ? Do you already know the address of the page `A` and `B` ?

Comment: yes I have...It is an offline app and every page is inside an assest folder and I have rename them as 1.html and 2.html and so on up to 7 pages and one main page i.e index.html

Comment: Well, then you have `WebView#getUrl()` to get the current Url being displayed by the `WebView` and you can use it on every backpress to check if its on page `A` or `B` and do accordingly. See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()). If that is what you want, I will edit the ans.